# insert a html as an object into html without scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to do is to edit text in word and save it as `text.html` then insert the `text.html` file in my `main.html`. My requirement is that in the `main.html` file, the text should:

1. have formatting
2. be able to show full content
3. be adjustable to the page size
4. not have scrollbars

My text is :

**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet**, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis luctus est a pulvinar luctus. Proin aliquet cursus turpis, in hendrerit magna porta vel. Mauris scelerisque scelerisque euismod. Donec dignissim lacinia leo, in euismod justo. Donec ut ligula non dui ornare vehicula. Etiam massa augue, venenatis sit amet egestas ac, dapibus eu sapien. **In ac sapien quis enim suscipit finibus.** Proin ut pretium arcu, vel mattis purus.

**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet**, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis luctus est a pulvinar luctus. Proin aliquet cursus turpis, in hendrerit magna porta vel. Mauris scelerisque scelerisque euismod. Donec dignissim lacinia leo, in euismod justo. Donec ut ligula non dui ornare vehicula. Etiam massa augue, venenatis sit amet egestas ac, dapibus eu sapien. **In ac sapien quis enim suscipit finibus.** Proin ut pretium arcu, vel mattis purus.

Or it can be anything. The point is to copy this text to word and save it as `text.html`, then my `main.html` will call it.

My `main.html` file is :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <object type="text/html" data="text.html" style="width:100%"></object>
    <p> this is a test </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, it doesn't work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Who downvoted please give reason

Comment: I just edited the question, hopefully it'r more clear now. BTW, it's fully reproducible.

Comment: I have just done it and it works properly... following the same steps.

Comment: @Fabio if you have a solution, post it as an answer so that OP can attempt to follow your steps.

Comment: @Fablo It doesn't show scrollbar? Maybe the text is too short?

Comment: Seems no one can answer the question

Comment: overflow and scrolling are not attributes of the object tag. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) for reference. You have to put these in the style attribute to make it work

Comment: Because your question says LOTS about importing files, and ends with _ The point is to copy this text to word and save it...._ - the ONLY mention of scrollbars is the title.  (Put another way - there's a very low signal-to-noise ratio in your question.  You included a LOT of irrelevant information, which made it unclear what you actually wanted).

Comment: I stated my 4 requirements at the beginning of the question. @cale_b

Comment: I'm trying to _help you_.  So - you can argue with me, or you can get the hint from the lack of answers: your question is unclear.  (You even said above "Seems no one can answer the question") - to which I responded with what the confusion is..... best of luck.  I hope you get it resolved!

Comment: Additionally - you asked why downvoted.  Again - _I'm trying to help you_ understand.  Sorry you don't like the answer's I'm providing, but they are at least _part_ of why you got downvoted, and why "no one can answer the question"

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `<object>` element has no `overflow` or `scrolling` attributes. `<iframe>` elements had the `scrolling` attribute, but this is deprecated in HTML5.

For the following solution, this markup will do:

```
<object class="text" data="text.html" type="text/html"></object>
```

And to modify its width and height, I'd recommend you separate your CSS into a separate style block (or stylesheet):

```
<style>
    .text {
        width: 400px;
        min-height: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

Hiding the scrollbar is a bit trickier as the scrollbar is inside the embedded HTML page. This means no HTML attribute or CSS property you declare in the parent page (`main.html`) will be able to hide the scrollbars in the child page (`text.html`). You may, however, access the DOM of the embedded page by using javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var object = document.querySelector('.text');
    var embeddedDocument = object.contentDocument;

    console.log( embeddedDocument.documentElement )
}
```

Now you can disable scrolling on the `<html>` and `<body>` elements of `text.html`. Note the `<html>` tag is accessed by referencing `documentElement`:

```
embeddedDocument.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
embeddedDocument.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

And if you want to resize the height of the whole `<object>` element based on the contents in `text.html` you set its height to match the `offsetHeight` of the `<body>` element in `text.html`:

```
var contentsHeight = embeddedDocument.body.offsetHeight;
object.height = contentsHeight;
```

So your whole code will look like this:

```
<style>
    .text {
        width: 400px;
        min-height: 100px;
    }
</style>

<object class="text" data="text.html" type="text/html"></object>

<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var object = document.querySelector('.text');
        var doc = object.contentDocument;

        doc.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        doc.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

        var contentsHeight = doc.documentElement.offsetHeight;
        object.height = contentsHeight;
    }
</script>
```

The snippets here at StackOverflow is a bit limited when it comes to embedding files, but you can test the above code in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r725rzj28q).

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for providing the detailed answer. I tried the sandbox and found that when we shrink the window size, the text will not adjust automatically. It will be covered instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. If what you want is to have the text contained within the viewport at all times, try changing the CSS to have the `<object>` adjust to the window size, e.g.: `.text { width: 400px; max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }`. This sets a static width of `400px`. Whenever the window shrinks to less than this width, `max-width:100%` will make sure it never stretches beyond the width of its parent. This will have to be adjusted to account for margins etc. Try playing around with the `width`, `min-width` and `max-width` properties and see if it gets you any closer :o)

Comment: Thank you! But now when I shrink the page, the text will be blocked due to insufficient height. Seems the min-height doesn't work?